# Exit insert mode in the JupyterLab using vim keybindings

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am using both the console and text editor within JupyterLab, and I set the text editor keymap to 'vim' and i can edit text just fine when in insert mode. But when trying to exit insert mode using the 'esc' key I just get toggled out of the current window. Is this not the way to exit insert mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now it will only work for the plain text editor. Look at this
[issue](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/1362) from the jupyterlab GitHub repository. If you want to enable the functionality you are looking for try this plugin [jupyterlab_vim](https://github.com/jwkvam/jupyterlab_vim).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue: Pressing esc in jupyterlab exits current window.

The solution in my case: Disable vimium in chrome for localhost

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this issue while using [tridactyl](https://github.com/tridactyl/tridactyl) on firefox.
As suggested by @Hunaphu, I fixed it disabling tridactyl on localhost.

After entering tridactyl `ex mode` (pressing `:`), run `blacklistadd http://localhost:8888/` or whatever localhost address you are using.